# Ag-Grid dropdown popup is hidden

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I'm trying to load a custom dropdown celleditor component into my Ag-Grid in Vue3. I have reproduced the issue here: https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-vue-3-example-forked-h5z6r5?file=/src/App.vue

The problem is that the options are hidden under the rows.
I have found one cheaty way of fixing this by overriding:

```
.ag-row-focus {
    z-index: 999;
}

.ag-grid-cell {
    overflow-y:visible !important;
    overflow-x:visible !important;
    z-index: 999 !important;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it's completely dependent on ag-row-focus. If a user has a specific row selected and then clicks on the dropdown of another row, say the one above, then the selected row is still another row and therefore, the options are still hidden. There were also other issues, for instance that the dropdown itself with these overflow settings do not respect the cell width and height anymore (especially the height). When the text is larger than intended, it is also when collapsed breaking the height rules for that cell.

Ag-Grid versions used:

```
"ag-grid-community": "26.1.0",
"ag-grid-vue3": "26.1.2",
```

Update:

I got most of the behavior now working by adding the css below. Remaining issue is that the text inside the dropdown also overflows and gets too big due to which it goes onto other cells & the height goes further than the row. Expected behavior is probably here that the text gets cut off.

```
.ag-grid-cell {
  overflow: visible !important;
  z-index: 10030 !important;
}
.ag-row {
  z-index: 0;
}

.ag-row.ag-row-focus {
  z-index: 1;
}
.ag-root-wrapper,
.ag-root,
.ag-body-viewport,
.ag-body-viewport-wrapper,
.ag-center-cols-clipper {
  overflow: visible !important;
  z-index: 5;
}

.ag-center-cols-viewport {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Updated sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-vue-3-example-forked-nvnhue?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Have you seen this example? https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/cell-editors/#example-dynamic-parameters 
Here the options are all accessible and it seems built in.  Even when the grid is 3 rows high I can still get to all the options

Comment: Late reply, but rich select is for enterprise only.